# How can I scale down a draw on canvas to fit screen size

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Firstly, sorry if the question isn't clear.

I have a multiplayer browser-based drawing game made with javascript and socket.io.

I have a canvas to draw on, and every 30ms, x and y positions are sent to the server which broadcast them to other players.

But this cause an issue, if someone (`a`) have a big screen, and someone (`b`) has a smaller one, `b` won't see the entire draw while `a` will see a small draw (comparatively to his screen size).

How can I scale up `b` draw on `a` screen, and scale down `a` draw on `b` screen ?

N.B: Source code for client side is available on drawmythings.esy.es/app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know know screen A and B's screen size (let's just take the width as same applies to height). To scale between A to B would be..

e.g. say A's screen is 2000 wide and B's is 1000 wide.

When A is viewing a point on B's screen:

`(A.screenWidth / B.screenWidth ) * B.x-position`

A position at x = 250 on B's screen = a quarter way across on A's screen = (2000 / 1000)  * 250 = 500 = a quarter way across on A's screen.

Conversely when B is viewing a point on A's screen:

`(B.screenWidth / A.screenWidth ) * A.x-position`

A position at x = 500 on A's screen = a quarter way across on B's screen = (1000 / 2000)  * 500 = 250 = a quarter way across on B's screen.

It seems to me the best bet would be to store the drawn co-ordinates in a "conceptual" screen of a constant size, say 2000 x 1500 (arbitrarily). So each point will have an x-position and y-position based on that scale.

When a user views it, you scale it to their current screen size by drawing it at `([users screen width] / 2000) * x-position`, same for the Y position and screen height.

That way the game has a "standard" set of boundaries so that limits on movement etc can be implemented using that, and the display is just that user's view of it. However I don't know how practical that would be with the program you're writing, and given you've already got some way ahead.

Comment: Just one thing, what is (  / 2000) ?

Comment: @FliiFe thanks-  when will I learn that chevrons < > around text hide it from Stack Exchange.. I've edited the text.

Comment: Oh, though that was a syntax I didn't know :-)